# Submersible well hasNew tank andpressure switch all plumbing new on surface. Water great for 6-7 gallons, water stops then back 30 seconds

Tags: electrical, plumbing, water, repair, well

Submersible well; Has New tank and pressure switch all plumbing new on surface. Submersible pump 150' down. Hose pressure great for 5-8 gallons then no water. Shut off for 30 seconds and water is back for same time?

Comment: Top of question  6-7 not 67, my bad for not reviewing.

Comment: You can [edit] to correct that. Sounds like you're overdrawing the well, and the static level is really close to the pump if it's only 6-7 gallons. Set pump deeper, restrict flow, drill well deeper so you can set pump deeper if there's presently no room below pump setting, etc...

Comment: If you draw 4 gallons, then pause 30 seconds, then draw 4 gallons and repeat, what happens? How was the well working before all the surface stuff was replaced? *i.e.* what went wrong that you chose to do that? Is the new pressure tank much larger than the old one?